# Taking the reciprocal of a Fraction

Tags: python, fractions, python-fractions

I want to take the reciprocal of `Fraction` in python, and do so in-place. The `Fraction` class does not provide a method for doing so (in my knowledge). I tried to just swap numerator and denominator:

```
f = Fraction(2, 3)
f.numerator, f.denominator = f.denominator, f.numerator
```

but it resulted in an `AttributeError: can't set attribute`.

I've also used the method of just constructing an new `Fraction`:

```
f = Fraction(2, 3)
f = Fraction(f.denominator, f.numerator)
```

which does in fact work, but creating a new object and deleting the old one doesn't seem very 'pythonic', i.e. unnecessarily complex. Is there a better way to take the reciprocal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from fractions import Fraction

spam = Fraction(2, 3)
eggs = spam ** -1
print(repr(eggs))
```

output

```
Fraction(3, 2)
```

EDIT:
As suggested in comments by [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) `1 / spam` also works:

```
from fractions import Fraction

spam = Fraction(2, 3)
eggs = 1 / spam 
print(repr(eggs))
```

Comment: So the `Fraction` class has a power operator implementation. Noted, and thanks.

Comment: Why not `eggs = 1 / spam`?

Comment: @martineau, right, that should also work. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

i think `f**-1` this will do the job

Comment: if this works for you accept as Answer. it will help to spread knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

`Fractions` are immutable like many (all?) Python numbers, which is why you can't change their attributes. The workaround is to define a function that creates and returns a *new* instances of the class based on the attributes of the one passed to it. Two ways of doing this are shown below.

```
from fractions import Fraction


def reciprocal(f):
    """ Return reciprocal of argument (an instance of Fraction). """
    return Fraction(f.denominator, f.numerator)

# Alternative implementation.
reciprocal = lambda f: Fraction(f.denominator, f.numerator)


f = Fraction(2, 3)
print(f)  # -> 2/3
print(repr(f))  # -> Fraction(2, 3)
r = reciprocal(f)
print(r)  # -> 3/2
print(repr(r))  # -> Fraction(3, 2)
```